# Referenced from errors after updating xcode to xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5.1

I updated Xcode 5.0.1 to Xcode 5.1. Then I ran the app in simulator, it works fine without any  issue. I ran it in device with developer provisioning profile, it worked. But when I tried to archive the app for adhoc distribution, it gave me lot of referenced form errors and so much of warnings.

[image]

I searched for the solution, but can't get that. Please help me to fix.

Comment: I also faced same problem. If I removed arm64 from Valid Architectures. It is fixed.

Comment: @Vidhyanand, I removed arm64 from Valid Architectures. Is it enough? or need to remove also from Architectures?

Comment: No need to remove from Architectures..@NAZIK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like libraries you are using in your project are not compiled for arm64 architecture. Make sure you have updated libraries, you can check the architectures your library support using:

xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info YOUR_LIB.a

Alternatively you can remove arm64 from ARCHS and VALID_ARCHS.

Comment: If I remove arm64 from ARCHS and VALID_ARCHS, will it affect anything in future?

Comment: Your app will run in 32 Bit compatibility mode on 64 bit devices such as iPhone 5S.

See more details on supporting arm64 here:

https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-09-27-arm64-and-you.html

Comment: Will Apple accept 32 Bit compatibility mode on 64 bit devices?

Comment: Please read the link I shared, here is abstract from it:

It's important to note that the A7 includes a full 32-bit compatibility mode that allows running normal 32-bit ARM code without any changes and without emulation. This means that the iPhone 5S runs old iPhone apps with no problem and no performance impact compared to other hardware. 32-bit code does potentially run with somewhat reduced performance since it gets none of the advantages of ARM64.